# How to use a single Sql Server Transaction between multiple page requests in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, transactions

I need to store records in multiple dependent tables of database, updated partially in each HTTP Request to Asp.net MVC Action.

For this I need to use a Sql Server Transaction across multiple Page Requests that are hitting Asp.Net MVC Action Methods.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data in objects while it's still not ready to be saved.

Some examples:

1) Store data in objects in [session](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/).

2) You can create a Manager class (with a singleton object living through the entire lifetime of your application) which will allow you to gather data across multiple requests. If you use IOC container, just register is as a singleton.

3) You can store the data client-side in cookies or local storage and push all of the data with another request when it's ready.

And then when you have a complete data set you can just save it to the database the normal way.

**EDIT**

If you insist on using transactions you can use the same principle here simply keep you transaction or a database context in the session instead of the data. However, I would advise against performing long running transactions. This may cause nasty locks on your tables. Yes, you can play with isolation levels, but I believe there are betters solutions.

How about a message bus e.g. MassTransit with a [Saga](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/sagas/) instead? When the saga is complete you can simply transfer its data to the database.

Comment: I don't want to use Session, as the data may grow big enough to eat up memory. And also, I want to learn, how to use Transaction in this way.